# addCurveToPoint crashing with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: cocoa, bezier, nsbezierpath

I'm trying to draw a bezier curve in cocoa and I'm getting a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION that doesn't seem to make any sense at all.

here's my code:

```
NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
[path setLineWidth: 1.0f];

NSPoint a = NSMakePoint(0, 0);
NSPoint c1 = NSMakePoint(0, 50);
NSPoint c2 = NSMakePoint(50, 100);
NSPoint b = NSMakePoint(100, 100);

[path moveToPoint:a];
[path addCurveToPoint: b controlPoint1:c1 controlPoint2:c2];

[[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] set];

[path stroke];
```

My application crashes when the following line is executed:

```
[path addCurveToPoint: b controlPoin1:c1 controlPoint2:c2];
```

And Xcode tells me it crashes in my main loop:

```
[NSApp runModalSession:modalSession];
```

The error output is the following:

```
2016-12-08 04:38:35.344601 unit_tests[10606:777278] -[NSBezierPath addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100428fa0
```

(lldb)

Comment: I strongly doubt the callstack is "completely useless": post it, and let potential helpers decide instead?

Comment: edited the question to include the output

Comment: that's not a stack trace, though, that's a single line. Where's the rest of the trace?

Comment: The implication is that when we get to that line, `path` no longer points to a UIBezierPath. It sounds like a threading issue. This might happen if this code is running simultaneously on multiple background threads, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo with `controlPoin1: c1`  It should be `controlPoint1: c1`

Actually I've just realised you're targeting AppKit (NSBezierPath) not UIKit (UIBezierPath).

Edit:

For AppKit use: `-[NSBezierPath curveToPoint: controlPoint1: controlPoint2:]`

For UIKit use `-[UIBezierPath addCurveToPoint: controlPoint1: controlPoint2:]`

Comment: yes, that's right, I'm using NSBezierPath. Fixed the typo, but same result.

Comment: The methods are -[UIBezierPath addCurveToPoint: controlPoint1: controlPoint2:] and -[NSBezierPath curveToPoint: controlPoint1: controlPoint2:]

Comment: @DDP You should add that comment to your answer, because it looks like you solved it.

Comment: That's it! Thanks

Comment: @megamau Happy days! Now accept DDP's answer by clicking on the grey checkmark under the arrows. The checkmark should turn green.